# Apply CSS Animation to only one div

Tags: css, animation

Why is the `div` with `id="test"` being animated when I only apply animation to the `div with class content`?

How do I limit the animation to class "content"?

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  animation-name: bla;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  color: white;
  width: 300;
  height: 300;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

@keyframes bla {
  from { margin-top: -50px }
  to { margin-top: 50px; }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
 <div class="content">
   <div class="item">
  <img id="1" src="1.jpg">
  <h4>1</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
  <img id="2" src="2.jpg">
  <h4>2</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
  <img id="3" src="3.jpg">
  <h4>3</h4>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div> 
  <div id= "test">
 <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are changing margins (the space between elements)...what did you expect to have happen?

Comment: @Paulie_D How can I achieve the same animation without changing the margin?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey Zip did you check the answer I provided?

Comment: did you try position:absolute; in content class css??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transform/translation instead of margin:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  animation-name: bla;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.item {
  color: white;
  width: 300;
  height: 300;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
@keyframes bla {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="item">
        <img id="1" src="1.jpg">
        <h4>1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img id="2" src="2.jpg">
        <h4>2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img id="3" src="3.jpg">
        <h4>3</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="test">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are all the answers getting downvoted? I see that your answer too got downvoted, even though it looks perfect to me.
This kind of downvoting without mentioning any reason does not do any good.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the margin is pushing all the elements down, including #test.Instead of animating the margin-top property, you should change the "top" (position property). So change

```
  @keyframes bla {
        from {margin-top: -50px }
        to { margin-top: 50px; }
    }
```

to

```
  @keyframes bla {
        from {top: -50px }
        to { top: 50px; }
    }
```

```css
    .content{
     display: flex;
     flex: 1;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-between;
     margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     animation-name: bla;
     animation-duration: 4s;
     margin-top: 50px;
      position:relative;
    }

    .item{
     color: white;
     width: 300;
     height: 300;
    }

    h4{
     font-size: 24px;
     background-color: #3498DB;
     text-align: center;
    }

    img{
     margin-bottom: -20px;
    }

    @keyframes bla {
     from {top: -50px }
     to { top: 50px; }
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Test</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
       <div class="item">
        <img id="1" src="1.jpg">
        <h4>1</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <img id="2" src="2.jpg">
        <h4>2</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <img id="3" src="3.jpg">
        <h4>3</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div> 

     <div id= "test">
      <p>hello</p>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with the "top" property, not the "margin-top" property. The top attribute basically defines the y-position from the top of the browser, but also depends on what is defined in the position attribute as well. The margin-top specifies the element's top gap from another element.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Maybe you want something like this.

```
<div class="element"></div>

.element {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
animation: pulse 5s infinite; 
} 

@keyframes pulse {
0% { 
background-color: #001F3F;
 }
100% {
 background-color: #FF4136
 }

 } 

html, 
 body {
height: 100%; 
 }
```